# not able to use $pull (Mongoose) to remove an object in an array for a user model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried various methods and ways to do it, I am trying to use the $pull method

This is my user object

[image]

I previously only had the object id in the user object , but now that I am removing a full object, I search for the ID of the posting, then try to pull that out

```
    router.delete('/testing', (req, res, next) => {
    postModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.query.postid, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
        if (error) return next(error);

        userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            // { email: req.query.email, posts: req.query.postid },
            { email: req.query.email },
            { $pull: { posts: { number: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.postid) } } },
            { new: true },
            function(error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    res.json(error);
                }
                console.log(`Post id ===== ${req.query.postid}`);
                console.log(`Email===== ${req.query.email}`);
                console.log(`returning user====${user}`);
                res.json('Successfully updated user');
            }
        );
    });
});
```

the post is being deleted from the postmodel, but I am not able to remove the object from the users postings made array.

any alternative solutions or insights as to why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: `{ $pull: { posts: { number: req.query.postid } } }` ==> Is there a property named `number` in the `posts` array. Because its not there in the sample you've provided.

Comment: sorry that was so weird.... I copied it again.

Comment: I also tried ```{ $pull: { "posts.$.number" : req.query.postid }},``` but no cookie :(

Comment: for the posts.$.number I get a error: ```"errmsg": "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.",```  maybe because I need to enter the object or something?

Comment: @jcx3x is `req.query.postid` a string or an `ObjectId` ?

Comment: its an object Id, I already tried to convert the type to object ID but it did not seem to effect the result,I can update this post with that code.

Comment: @mickl it worked, I guess I was using the conversion for ObjectId for other methods, but I decided it did not work, using it with this method it worked, you can post an answer so I can close this question?

Comment: Do you check directly in the database if it was updated ? Or do you just console.log(user) ?

Comment: @Abk I do both, I check using postman, I also have mongoDB open on a tab because its cloud db, the postman queries the db anyhow but.. I also console user info on any page change ( react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MongoDB compares types before values and there's no implicit type conversion applied so instead of having:

```
{ $pull: { posts: { number: req.query.postid } } }
```

you need to run:

```
{ $pull: { posts: { number: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.postid) } } }
```